# Adding class to each li automatically when pressing a button in a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using JCarousel(circular), i made one list of items, where i want to add a class dynamically for each li after clicking a button,that too the class should be added one li after another.
so,for each click, only one li should have that class,so that i can write css for that class.
is there any jquery or javascript way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function(){   
    $('li.liclass:not(.your_class)')[0].addClass('your_class'); 
});
```